# Ng-models not accessible

Tags: angularjs

One of the ng-models gives null value. When I click the button with the function `setNewRecord` the parameter `selectedDocument` is null. The first two parameters are correct. The javascript code is added as well.

```
<form name="myForm" >
<div>
    <select ng-model="selectedCompany">
        <option value="">-- Select Company --</option>
        <option data-ng-repeat="currentSetting in currentSettings" value={{currentSetting.SCACCode}}>{{currentSetting.SCACCode}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div><input id="Text1" type="text"  ng-model="enteredCustomer"/></div>
<div>
   <select ng-model="selectedDocument" ng-click="getTypes(selectedCompany, enteredCustomer)">
       <option value="">-- Select Doc type --</option>
       <option data-ng-repeat="docSetting in docSettings" value="{{docSetting.Doc_Type}}">{{docSetting.Doc_Type}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
<input id ="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add new record" ng-click="setNewRecord(selectedCompany, enteredCustomer,selectedDocument)"/>
```

Java Script

```
myApp.service('getDocTypesService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
var allSettings = null;
this.getDocTypes = function(compName, custName) {
    var def = $q.defer()
    if (allSettings) {
        def.resolve(allSettings);
    } else {
        $http.post('GetDocTypes', {
                companyName: compName,
                customerName: custName
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                var response = $.parseJSON(response.data)
                allSettings = response;
                def.resolve(allSettings);
            });
    }
    return def.promise;
}
}]);



myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'getDocTypesService',
function($scope, getDocTypesService) {
    $scope.getTypes = function(comp, cust) {
        getDocTypesService.getDocTypes(comp, cust).then(function(value) {
            $scope.docSettings = value
        });
    };

}
]);
```

Comment: The problem will probably be in fetching the docSettings on ng-click="getTypes" in the select. The values in the options will not rerender as no digest will be triggered. You may look at ng-options (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) which could solve it. However without the javascript code I am just guessing...

Comment: Can we please see your controller code?

Comment: I added the javascript

Comment: @user6440175 -  I don't see setNewRecord() in your controller code.  Other than that, why are you passing selectedCompany, enteredCustomer,and selectedDocument into the func as params?  They are bound to your model on scope so you should just use them in your func as $scope.selectedCompany, $scope.enteredCustomer, and $scope.selectedDocument

Comment: jbrown Could you show me how to use them in my function

Comment: Thank you, jbrown I modified my code

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the select for selectedDocument with this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedDocument" 
        ng-click="getTypes(selectedCompany, enteredCustomer)" 
        ng-options="docSetting.Doc_Type for docSetting in docSettings track by docSetting.Doc_Type">
</select>
```

Comment: What do you see as values inside select's options?

Comment: <option data-ng-repeat="docSetting in docSettings" value="Test" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Test</option>

Comment: Well that's really strange. You can try adding ng-change="changeHandler()" and define the changehandler in your controller to console.log($selectedDocument), We'll see if the change is triggered at all...